# Picking up variable-name params in Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My form generates a field for each member of a variable-length collection and assigns the input field the ID of the collection member ID. I.e.,

```
<input type="text" id="1" val="Value for collection member with id #1">
<input type="text" id="5" val="Value for collection member with id #5">
```

In the controller I'm trying to pick up these values by iterating over the collection like this:

```
  collectors.each do |col|
    amount = params[col.id]
    # ...process this value
  end
```

But I'm getting a nil value error at amount = params[col.id]. How can I access these variables?

**EDIT** I just changed it so I use javascript to generate a array of hashes of the KV pairs and stick it into a hidden field so my controller can evaluate that. It works but from a security perspective, how awful is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
<input type="text" id="1" val="Value for collection member with id #1">
<input type="text" id="5" val="Value for collection member with id #5">
```

with

```
<input type="text" id="1" name="1" val="Value for collection member with id #1">
<input type="text" id="5" name="5" val="Value for collection member with id #5">
```

In the controller

```
collectors.each do |col|
  amount = params[col.id] if params[col.id]
  # ...process this value
end
```

Comment: Actually, nevermind, it's the same error :/ Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "each" try:

```
amount = collectors.map(&:id)
```

Comment: that will just yield an array of amount values, right? How do I know which is associated with each id?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what your form output is supposed to be. Could you elaborate on that? How are you generating the input fields?